# Facing issue to print arraylist

Tags: javascript, angularjs

> Code:

```
var cspaObj = {};
var associatedCspaList = responseData.data.associatedCspaList;
responseData.data.associatedCspaList = [];
angular.forEach(associatedCspaList, function (value, key) {
  cspaObj.clientId = value.slice(0, 4);
  cspaObj.systemId = value.slice(4, 8);
  cspaObj.principleId = value.slice(8, 12);
  cspaObj.agentId = value.slice(12, 16);
  responseData.data.associatedCspaList.push(cspaObj);
});
```

> Below are the associatedCspaList

```
 "associatedCspaList": [
  "1000100010001000",
  "2000200020002000",
  "3000300030003000",
  "9999100020003000",
  "9999999999999999"
]
```

> Need to print like below:

```
1000 1000 1000 1000
2000 2000 2000 2000
3000 3000 3000 3000
9999 1000 2000 3000
9999 9999 9999 9999
```

But above code only printed last one 9999 9999 9999 9999. It will not printed remaining values so please help me into that. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a simple solution you can loop through all the chars in this string and put a space after 4 chars.

Comment: please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re only creating one object and adding it multiple times to your list. This causes all references to be to the same object and therefore have the same values. Create a new object every time:

```
var associatedCspaList = responseData.data.associatedCspaList;
responseData.data.associatedCspaList = [];
angular.forEach(associatedCspaList, function (value, key) {
  var cspaObj = {}; // Create the object here, not outside
  cspaObj.clientId = value.slice(0, 4);
  cspaObj.systemId = value.slice(4, 8);
  cspaObj.principleId = value.slice(8, 12);
  cspaObj.agentId = value.slice(12, 16);
  responseData.data.associatedCspaList.push(cspaObj);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your cspaObj variable should be inside the loop.

```js
var associatedCspaList = [
  "1000100010001001",
  "2000200020002000",
  "3000300030003000",
  "9999100020003000",
  "9999999999999999"
];

var associatedCspaListResponse = [];

angular.forEach(associatedCspaList, function (value, key) {
  var cspaObj = {};
  var output = "";
  cspaObj.clientId = value.slice(0, 4);
  cspaObj.systemId = value.slice(4, 8);
  cspaObj.principleId = value.slice(8, 12);
  cspaObj.agentId = value.slice(12, 16);
  
  // expected output
  console.log(cspaObj.clientId + " " + cspaObj.systemId + " " + cspaObj.principleId + " " + cspaObj.agentId );
  
  //response
  
  associatedCspaListResponse.push(cspaObj);
});
console.log("response");
console.log(associatedCspaListResponse);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution... :):)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
$scope.associatedCspaList = [
  "1000100010001000",
  "2000200020002000",
  "3000300030003000",
  "9999100020003000",
  "9999999999999999"
];

$scope.clientId = $scope.associatedCspaList[0].replace(/(\d{4})/g, '$1 ').replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/, '');
$scope.systemId = $scope.associatedCspaList[1].replace(/(\d{4})/g, '$1 ').replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/, '');
$scope.principleId = $scope.associatedCspaList[2].replace(/(\d{4})/g, '$1 ').replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/, '');
$scope.agentId = $scope.associatedCspaList[3].replace(/(\d{4})/g, '$1 ').replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/, '');
```

Comment: @rahul-pawar: its working fine at my end. please check.

Comment: Thanks for your solution... :):)

Answer (score 0):

Make the below code run.

```
var cspaObj = {};
var associatedCspaList = responseData.data.associatedCspaList;
responseData.data.associatedCspaList = [];
associatedCspaList.map(function(value, key) {
  cspaObj.clientId = value.slice(0, 4);
  cspaObj.systemId = value.slice(4, 8);
  cspaObj.principleId = value.slice(8, 12);
  cspaObj.agentId = value.slice(12, 16);
  cspaObj.main = cspaObj.clientId + ' ' + cspaObj.systemId + ' ' +    cspaObj.principleId + ' ' + cspaObj.agentId;
  responseData.data.associatedCspaList.push(cspaObj.main);
});
console.log('data', responseData.data.associatedCspaList);
```